# Java - how to split a string into a new line, after every punctuation mark?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on an Android app, and I have a method which gets a String as an input, and displays it on the screen. The problem is that the text is too wide, 
and some of it goes out of the screen. So I would like to split the string into new lines after every punctuation mark.

So, instead of having: `"This is a string. It does not have new lines"`, I would like to have

```
"This is a string. 
It does not have new lines".
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Look for `\p{Punct}` in the javadoc of the Pattern class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace every `punctuation mark` with `punctuation mark + new line character`.

So here:

```
String str="This is a string. It does not have new lines";
str=str.replaceAll("\\.\\s?","\\.\n");
System.out.println(str);
```

will print String as :

```
This is a string.
It does not have new lines
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How about other punctuation signs?

Comment: @YCF_L Yes that was the mistake I have made. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

## Only the dot(.)

If you want to replace the dot you can use :

```
String str = "This is a string. It does not have new lines.";
str = str.replaceAll("\\.\\s?", "\\.\n");
```

I make `\\s?` because you can get a sentence which haven't any space between the dot and the character :

```
This is a string.It does not have new lines
//--------------^^
```

**Output**

```
This is a string.
It does not have new lines.
```

## All the punctuation

**Punctuation:** One of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

In case you want all the punctuation you can use the solution of @assylias mention in comment, you can use `\p{Punct}` like this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\p{Punct})\\s?", "$1\n");
```

So you can use this pattern like a group `(\p{Punct})`, because when you replace it the punctuation is replaced also, so to avoid this, you can replace it with this group `(punctuation) + new line` like this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\p{Punct})\\s?", "$1\n");
```

## Only some punctuation

In case you want to use just some punctuation and not all for example just `.,;`, you can use `[.,;]` like this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("([.,;])\\s?", "$1\n");
```

Comment: How about other punctuation signs?

Comment: what about the 2ed solution @assylias ?